# rowSums error 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r

I am attempting to add various column together with `rowSums` but I am having some issues. Here is a list of column names:

```
colnames(No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff)

"CHROM" "POS"   "REF"   "ALT"   "QUAL"  "ANN.ALLELE"    "ANN.EFFECT"
"ANN.IMPACT"    "ANN.GENE"  "ANN.GENEID"    "ANN.FEATURE"   "ANN.FEATUREID"
"ANN.HGVS_C"    "ANN.HGVS_P"    "ANN.ERRORS"    "GEN.C02141.GT" "GEN.C00611.GT"
"GEN.C00633.GT" "GEN.C00634.GT" "GEN.C00644.GT" "GEN.C00647.GT" "GEN.C00648.GT"
"GEN.C00649.GT" "GEN.C00650.GT" "GEN.C00653.GT" "GEN.C00655.GT" "GEN.C00656.GT"
"GEN.C00657.GT" "GEN.C00659.GT" "GEN.C00682.GT" "GEN.C00705.GT" "GEN.C00707.GT"
"GEN.C00720.GT" "GEN.C00783.GT" "GEN.C01431.GT" "GEN.C01944.GT" "GEN.C01943.GT"
"GEN.C01403.GT" "GEN.C01158.GT" "GEN.C01157.GT" "GEN.C01156.GT" "GEN.C01033.GT"
"GEN.C00736.GT" "GEN.C00639.GT" "GEN.C99686.GT"
```

All of the columns that I am working with are labled `GEN.Cxxxxx.GT` and all the values in those column range from 0-2. I am trying to sum columns 20:29 and column 45 and then put the values in a new column called `controls`:

```
No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores$controls <- rowSums(No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores[,20:29,45])
```

but when I try running that command I get the following error:

```
Error in rowSums(No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores[, 20:29, 45]) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Data

```
str(No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores)

'data.frame':   1000 obs. of 11 variables:
$ GEN.C00644.GT: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 3 1 1 3 3 3 2 1 3 1 ...
$ GEN.C00647.GT: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 3 1 3 3 2 2 2 1 2 1 ...
$ GEN.C00648.GT: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 3 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 2 1 ...
$ GEN.C00649.GT: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 3 1 1 3 2 2 2 1 2 1 ...
...
```

Comment: You have an error: `rowSums(No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores[,c(20:29,45)])` need to wrap `20:29, 45` in `c()`

Comment: That didn't do it either `No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores$controls <- rowSums(No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores[,c(20:29,45)])` `Error in rowSums(No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores[, c(20:29, 45)]) : 
  'x' must be numeric`

Comment: Are you sure that all the values in those columns are `numeric` as opposed to `factor` or `character` values containing numbers? Providing the output of `str(No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores[, c(20:29, 45)])` might help

Comment: Please post a sample of your actual data, not just the names of columns. Otherwise we're just guessing as to what the typing issue is. But as @emilliman5 said, proper indexing in R takes the form `data[, c(1, 3, 5:7)]`, not `data[, 1, 3, 5:7]`

Comment: @Brian I've added your `str` output to the question. In the future, additional information should be added as edits to the question, not as comments. For posting data, use the `dput` function. You should read this page to find out how to make a great question that gets fast and good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting this error because the values are not `numeric`. Look at your output from `str`:

```r
GEN.C00650.GT: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 3 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 3 1 ...
```

These are class `factor`, not class `numeric`. To work with them as numbers, you need to convert them to  numbers using `as.numeric`

### If you can import your data again:

If you can import your data from the file again, you can do so with the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument. You should almost always use this argument, since without it, all strings (and most numbers, as you see here) will be converted in to factors creating all kinds of annoying problems until you change them back.

As of [R 4.0.0, this is no longer necessary](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/), as the default value of `stringsAsFactors` has been changed to `FALSE`. This will hopefully make this common mistake a thing of the past

### Otherwise, to change from a Factor back to a Number:

#### Base R

The simplest way to do this is to use `sapply`:

```r
rowSums(sapply(No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores[, c(20:29, 45)],
               function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
```

This subsets your data.frame, applies the `as.numeric` function to each row, and then calculates `rowSums`.

#### tidyverse

You can also use the `mutate_if` function from `dplyr` to convert all factor variables to numeric.

```r
library(dplyr)

No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores <- No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, ~as.numeric(as.character(.)))

rowSums(No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores[, c(20:29, 45)])
```

Alternately, you could use `mutate_at` to select columns by position or name. Read `?select` to see all the different way you can select columns. You can even use a regular expression with `matches`, as below:

```
No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores <- No_Low_No_Intergenic_snpeff.scores %>%
    mutate_at(vars(matches('GEN.C\\d{5}.GT')), funs(as.numeric))
```

This applies the function `as.numeric` to all columns whose names match the regular expression `GEN.C\\d{5}.GT`, where `\\d{5}` represents 5 numeric digits.

Comment: hmmm this makes a lot of sense. Let me give a try real quick

Comment: Is there a way to have dyplyr only change select columns? Right now it is change all my data into as.numeric

Comment: @Brian yes, either `mutate_at` to specify columns by name or position, or `mutate_if` to specify columns based on a predicate, as shown above